# Targeted ads in iOS app

Tags: ios, admob, ads, targeting

**How can I put targeted ads in iOS apps?** I downloaded an iOS app that has very well targeted ads from DoubleClick.

I'd like to target by keywords that I supply. For example I'd like to specify "fishing", "outdoors" and "camping" and have relevant ads served to my iOS app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did in this situation was that I used (HTML) AdSense. It does seem illogical but there are some good sides to it if You get it right.

Comment: That makes sense. I assume you embedded it in a `UIWebView`. I'm curious about Google's take on developers deciding to display ads in a mobile app that are in some ways destined for the browser.

Comment: Yes, but it wasn't a big problem as some other parts of the app were made in HTML too; I think it might be a problem if You'd have a WebView displaying just the ad.